# generating compiled Tkinter python code

Tags: python, tkinter

I've noticed that when creating a GUI using Tkinter in python, when running the final .py/.pyw file, I'm not presented with a .pyc file.
I'd like to give my application to someone for personal usage, without giving him the full source code.
Is there anyway of forcing the interpreter to generate a pyc file, or any other way to get nothing but python bytecode without using py2exe or cxfreeze or similar things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import py_compile
py_compile.compile(r'/path/to/your/file.py')
```

Comment: Or in one line: python -c "import py_compile; py_compile.compile(r'/path/to/your/file.py')"

Comment: Anyway to make this work with pyw's?
That is, compiling to pyc and getting rid of the command window still?